Moodle SQL SCORM-Report - student_response and patterns
In Moodle 4.3, the SCORM data was divided into 3 database tables. Is it possible to evaluate the number of "value" of student_response for the respective name of " cmd.interactions_[nr].id?
Example:
So far it has worked with a selfjoin to the table.



Slide-ID
student_response
count of answer




Scene1_Slide1_Multichoice_0_0
Richtig
2



SELECT 
    concat('<a target="_new" href="%%WWWROOT%%/course/view.php?id=',c.id,'">',c.shortname,'</a>')  as course,
    sca.scormid,
    sc.name ,
     sca.attempt,
    scelem.element,
    slide.value as "Question",
 
    @answer:=(
        SELECT scval.value 
        FROM prefix_scorm_scoes_value AS scval 
            JOIN prefix_scorm_element AS scelem2 ON scelem2.id = scval.elementid
        WHERE scval.scoid = slide.scoid 
            AND scval.attemptid = slide.attemptid
            AND scelem2.element = concat (LEFT(scelem.element, LENGTH(scelem.element)-3) , '.student_response') 
   ) AS "resultvalue" ,
   @answer:=(
        SELECT scval.value 
        FROM prefix_scorm_scoes_value AS scval 
            JOIN prefix_scorm_element AS scelem2 ON scelem2.id = scval.elementid
        WHERE scval.scoid = slide.scoid 
            AND scval.attemptid = slide.attemptid
            AND scelem2.element = concat (LEFT(scelem.element, LENGTH(scelem.element)-3) , '.pattern') 
   ) AS "pattern" 
   
 
   
FROM prefix_scorm AS sc
JOIN prefix_scorm_attempt As sca ON sca.scormid=sc.id
JOIN prefix_scorm_scoes_value as slide ON slide.attemptid = sca.id
JOIN prefix_scorm_element as scelem on scelem.id = slide.elementid
JOIN prefix_course AS c ON c.id = sc.course
JOIN prefix_course_categories AS cats ON c.category = cats.id

        

WHERE 
    sc.course = 158 AND sc.name ="XY"

AND  NOT scelem.element LIKE '%cmi.suspend_data%' 
AND NOT scelem.element LIKE '%objectives%' 
 AND (scelem.element LIKE '%.id%' OR scelem.element LIKE '%.pattern%'    )


 GROUP BY       SUBSTRING_INDEX(slide.value, '_', 3)
ORDER BY  sca.attempt, slide.elementid


The above GROUP BY is invalid and expected to raise an error. Which dbms are you using?

A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

@jarlh The "group by"  statement works and is valid.
Why do you assume that this grouping does not work? I use SQL and the Moodle plugin https://moodle.org/plugins/block_configurable_reports to create the reports.
